# SSIS Excel Connection String Extended Properties: HDR=YES; Appears Twice

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am able to execute my SSIS via a batch file but I am unable to execute it in Visual Studio 2010. We are using this for our scheduled jobs so it is fine.

I am extracting records from SQL Server and generate to an Excel document. I am using a DTS Configuration File when I execute the batch file thus there are no errors.

However, I would like to run this in Visual Studio as well.

This is because the Excel Connection String in Visual Studio is as follows:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=xxx.xls;Extended Properties=HDR=YES;EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;
```

May I know why does `HDR=YES` appears twice and how do I to solve the issue above?

Comment: I think you can remove first `HDR=YES;` ;).

Comment: What actual error do you get? Either you typed it in, it was loaded from a config, or it is an expression. You are the only one with the package so only you can work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Connecting to Excel**
>
> The Microsoft Jet provider is used to connect to an Excel workbook. In the following connection string, the Extended Properties keyword sets properties that are specific to Excel. **"HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains column names, not data**, and "IMEX=1;" tells the driver to always read "intermixed" data columns as text.
>
> ```
> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""
> ```
>
> Note that the double quotation character required for the Extended Properties must also be enclosed in double quotation marks.